# Class alias with independent properties

Tags: php

I'm trying to create instances of a class but I'm having difficulties to have them have their own independent property values.

```
class A{
    public static $value = NULL;
}

for ($i=0; $i <= 1; $i++) { 
    class_alias('A', 'A'.$i);
}

A0::$value = 1;
echo A0::$value; // echo 1
A1::$value = 9;
echo A1::$value; // echo 9
echo A0::$value; // echo 9
```

Here, `A0::$value` should echo the value '1'.

I know they are alias so the only thing that changes is the name they are called by.

The `class` I'm working on has lots of static `methods` and `properties` and I need to be able to call it like this `A0::method()` from any part of the code so I can't just create instances of the class inside variables like this:

```
$A1 = new A();
$A2 = new A();
```

How can I create instances of a class where I can call it statically without the use of variables and have it with its own property values independent from other alias?

Comment: For this you have to change your static stuff to non-static stuff, so you can assign an instance to a variable and change it as you want

Comment: I can't use variables for this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't do that.

Static members are "bound" to the  given class, not an object. So every change performed on them will be visible on every alias/object created from your class.

You have to rethink your code.